# How to use Drupal 8 with a Nginx server?

Tags: nginx, virtual-machine, drupal-8

I just migrated my Drupal 8 site from an Apache server to Nginx.

I applied the configuration below :

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/

I do not understand what this block is for. Should I enter the IP address of my server instead of this one ?

```
# Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule will only be useful if you have **.txt** or **.log** files in a directory accessible through the web server.

If that is the case, for security reasons, you should list all ip addresses that can access those files. All other addresses will be banned.

However, it is very unlikely that you want to serve log files via http, so you could just deny all.

More information in the nginx docs:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html